# Save as PDF breaks bookmarks MS Office 2016 on Mac High Sierra

Tags: pdf, ms-office, bookmarks, macos-high-sierra

I was using Open Office up until recently and links from our newsletter to bookmarks in the PDF has been working without problem.

Last friday I tried to make the same with MS Office 2016 Word. 15.41 (171205) on Mac OS 10.13.2 (17C88) High Sierra but I couldn't get it to work. And I started reading on forums and google and saw something about cross referencing, that didn't work either.

So. What am I doing wrong? It can't be this hard to make a bookmark and have it point to the correct page, can it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From another forum: [technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/87cf182e-0d28-4619-bdbd-f2e651460337/bookmarks-breaks-on-save-as-pdf-on-mac-os-high-sierra?forum=Office2016forMac)

Hi,

It seems that the bookmarks inserted in Word for Mac 2016 cannot be exported to PDF when using Save As PDF feature. I also tried on my Mac with Word for Mac version 16.10 (180109) and MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2.

There's always something blocking my way! It never ends!! :(